# Adding time to calendar date in Linux gives incorrect result

Tags: linux, date, calendar, gnu, utc

I am on Linux and I am trying to add a certain number of days, hours and minutes to a specified calendar date using the date tool:

For example:

```
$ date -d "2013-01-01 + 305 days 12 hours 30 minutes" +"%Y%m%d%0k%M%S"
20131102123000
```

Splitting the result up so it's easier for us to read:

```
2013-11-02 12:30:00
```

This appears to be working correctly. However, when I add 306 days instead of 305:

```
$ date -d "2013-01-01 + 306 days 12 hours 30 minutes" +"%Y%m%d%0k%M%S"
20131103113000
```

Split:

```
2013-11-03 11:30:00
```

Notice how the hour now shows 11 instead of 12! But I told it to add 12 hours... Let me increment the day one more time:

```
$ date -d "2013-01-01 + 307 days 12 hours 30 minutes" +"%Y%m%d%0k%M%S"
20131104123000
```

And split the result again:

```
2013-11-04 12:30:00
```

Now the hour goes back to what I expected. I have tested this using date versions 8.12 and 8.4, the same result happens on both. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably it's because Daylight Saving Time shifts. Check the timezone and also add `%z %Z` to `date` pattern to see what's the timezone being used

Comment: This is definitely due to DST switch which took place on November 3rd in 2013 https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2013

Comment: You guys answered it. I was trying to add from a UTC date but the tool was interpreting my request as a local timezone. That would explain the DST switch.

Comment: Use the `-u` or `--utc` option to make the date be interpreted as UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to add from a UTC date, but I did not specify this to the tool. This is the solution:

```
date --utc -d "2013-01-01 + 307 days 12 hours 30 minutes" +"%Y%m%d%0k%M%S"
```

Because UTC does not observe DST, there will be no shifts in the hour.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else hits this snag, here's something I just discovered:

```bash
TZ=Africa/Johannesburg date -d "11 Dec 2023 09:00 +4 hours" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00
```

produces `2023-12-11T08:00:00+02:00`, ie an hour earlier instead of 4 hours later.

The way I got the correct answer was to split this into 2 steps:

```bash
d="$(TZ=Africa/Johannesburg date -d "11 Dec 2023 09:00" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00)"
TZ=Africa/Johannesburg date -d "$d +4 hours" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00
```

which produced the expected `2023-12-11T13:00:00+02:00`.